# Run Multiple Queries in a Transaction and Process Outputs Separately

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

Can I run multiple queries in a transaction and process the outputs separately. I am using mysql, mysqlpdo and php. For example,

```
try {
    $dbh->beginTransaction();

    // A set of queries; if one fails, an exception should be thrown
    $stmt1 = $dbh->prepare('first query');
    $stmt2 = $dbh->prepare('second query');
    $stmt3 = $dbh->prepare('third query');

    if ($stmt1->execute() && $stmt2->execute() && $stmt3->execute())
    {
        $dbh->commit();
    }

} catch(Exception $e) {
    $dbh->rollback();
}

// output data of each row
while ($rows = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ... }

// output data of each row
while ($rows = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ... }

// output data of each row
while ($rows = $stmt3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ... }
```

The queries produce different outputs which will be utilized differently.

Answer (score 0):

Using SELECT queries with a transaction makes no sense.

So just get rid of begin and commit stuff and just select your data.